# 英語が残っている: タグで検索したページのサイドバー: about とそのツールチップ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL例
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3  
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3

[image: about]

ツールチップ:

> tag wiki, stats and faq

Comment: ツールチップは適用済です。「about」は開発者の支援が必要。

Answer (score 1):

> about »

このタグについて »

> tag wiki, stats and faq

タグ wikiや統計情報、リンクの多い質問を見る